# React component to update child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a **React** component (`Albums`) which `render()` method returns one of two possible components, depending on its state. One of these components (`AlbumsTable`) is called with two props parameters, `classes` and `albums`. The second props parameter is an array obtained by an ajax using **Axios** in a method (`getData`) that updates `Albums` state causing its re-rendering.

Due to Ajax asynchronic nature, `Albums` renders twice, the first time with `this.albums = []`, and the second one (caused by `getData()` state update) with `this.albums` equal to the result of the ajax.

The problem is that I can trace that `AlbumsTable.constructor()` is called only once (the first time `Albums` renders), when `this.albums` equals `[]`. So the second time `Albums` renders, when `this.albums` equals the result of the ajax, this content is not sent as props to `AlbumsTable`, causing the result of the ajax not to be displayed never.

This is the code of my components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700,
  },
});

class AlbumsTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      classes: props.classes,
    }

    if(props.albums === undefined){
      this.albums = [];
    } else {
      this.albums = props.albums;
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Paper className={this.state.classes.root}>
        <Table className={this.state.classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Photos</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {this.albums.map(album => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={album.id}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {album.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{"photos"}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

class AlbumDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    return(<p>Album Detail Comming Soon...</p>);
  }
}

class Albums extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      classes: props.classes,
      mode: 'table',
      albums: [],
    };
    this.albums = [];
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
      const axios = require('axios');
      var userToken = Cookies.get('token');
      axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
      axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/api/albums/',
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: userToken,
          }
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.albums = response.data.results;
        this.setState({albums: this.state.albums + 1});
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return(null);
      })
    }

  setData(albums) {
    this.setState({albums: albums});
  }

  render() {  
    if(this.state.mode === 'table'){
      return (<AlbumsTable classes={this.state.classes} albums={this.albums} />);
    } else {
      return (<AlbumDetail />);
    }

  }
}

Albums.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Albums);
```

I guess I am missing or missunderstanding something about components rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you think your problem better, you can realize that you don’t need to save the `albums` array as a variable into the class component, would be better to check if your `albums` property is defined else you should return an empty array, in that way the component will work as expected.

```
render(){
    const albums = this.props.albums || [];
    return (
       <Paper className={this.state.classes.root}>
        <Table className={this.state.classes.table}>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Photos</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {albums.map(album => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={album.id}>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {album.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">{"photos"}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-rendering component won't cause it to be created once again. It will be updated instead, so `constructor` will not fire twice. This is a standard behaviour. You should use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` method to update state in response to props change. You can find more informations here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle